# Detect when Zsh is running within the subshell of another shell

Tags: zsh

This is a slightly esoteric Zsh question, of which there may not be a concrete answer.

I am trying to detect a particular context of a Zsh when instantiated in a particular way. How to do this is not immediately obvious given the environment variables commonly used for this purpose (such as `$SHLVL`, `$ZSH_SUBSHELL`, `$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT`, and `$-`), at least as far as I am aware.

Here is a Zsh instantiated in a normally detectable way:

```
export HELLO='world'
zsh -c 'echo "$SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT $- $HELLO"'
# 2 0 cmdarg 569X world
```

As opposed to a Zsh instantiated in a way that obscures detection:

```
export HELLO='world'
(zsh -c 'echo "$SHLVL $ZSH_SUBSHELL $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT $- $HELLO"')
# 1 0 cmdarg 569X world
```

The Zsh called within the subshell has access to the parent environment's variables, as is evident by the presence of `world`, however `$SHLVL` is tricked into reporting `1` and unfortunately `$ZSH_SUBSHELL`, with a value of `0`, is of no help in this case.

How can I detect, using standard detection methods, the fact that the second case has access to a parent environment? I don't want to have to rely on checking variables set by my self in the parent context that dirty the environment solely for this purpose, if I don't have to.

Perhaps it would help me if someone could explain how Zsh deciphers the `$SHLVL` and why placing that code in a subshell obscures that detection. My rough understanding is that the subshell forks the environment (anything that is exported), and that `$SHLVL` is not exported.

Comment: `$SHLVL` is  exported. That's how it works, a shell adds one to the one it gets from the environment on start-up. Why it's decreased in subshells in `zsh` (`printenv SHLVL` vs `(printenv SHLVL)`) I'm not sure. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I've raised the issue to the `zsh` development mailing list. Looks like http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02472.html could be the culprit. The problem doesn't show up with zsh 3.1.5

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check; it made me to think to try from bash, and I've now noticed that `(zsh)` in bash has the expected `$SHLVL` of `2`. So, the inconsistent/unexpected behavior is probably a bug!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can you link to the mailing list issue that you raised?

Comment: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01574.html no answer yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a [bug](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01574.html) (regression) introduced in 1999 by [that change](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1999/msg02472.html) and now fixed (by [that change](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01609.html) ([commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/8ce98c75f5330eecfa474e342146b8d057abcefc/)))

Basically, in:

```
(cmd1; cmd2)
```

`zsh` forks a child process for the subshell, then another process for `cmd1`. But for `cmd2`, given that it's the last command in the subshell, `zsh` optimises out the fork. That's as if we had done:

```
(cmd1; exec cmd2)
```

Or in other words, `zsh` does an *implicit*/*fake* `exec` here.

Now the bug was that in that case, `zsh` *forgot* that we were in a subshell and assumed that *implicit* `exec` was actually *terminating* the shell (replacing it with `cmd2`), and was then decrementing `$SHLVL` as `cmd2`'s parent would not be `zsh` anymore.

Here however, we're in a subshell, so that *implicit `exec`* is not terminating the shell.

Thanks for bringing that up. That allowed to fix it and find related bugs [in `bash`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-09/msg00000.html) and [`tcsh`](http://bugs.gw.com/view.php?id=572).

Comment: Thanks for pursuing this. I love the fact that it goes so far back in history regardless of the fact that it's an issue.