# Zsh nested command args $SHLVL bug?

Tags: zsh

I am wondering if some behavior I am observing with Zsh version 5.2 is related to another possible bug I stumbled upon and asked about in a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304917/185851).

The following code:

```
zsh -c "zsh -c 'zsh -c \"echo \$SHLVL\"'"
```

Echo's out `2` for `$SHLVL`. Compare this with:

```
sh -c "zsh -c 'zsh -c \"echo \$SHLVL\"'"
```

Where it echo's out `3` for `$SHLVL`.

Is this a possible bug similar to the one outlined in my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304917/185851)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit:

```
$ SHLVL=1 zsh -c 'echo $SHLVL; zsh -c "echo \$SHLVL"'
2
2
$ SHLVL=1 zsh -c 'echo $SHLVL; zsh -c "echo \$SHLVL"; true'
2
3
```

What's happening is that if the last command is an external command, zsh executes it without forking — a tail call optimization. You can observe this by echoing `$$` in addition to `SHLVL`: in the first case, the nested invocation of zsh has the same PID; in the second case, the nested invocation runs as a child process because the parent stays behind to run `true` afterwards.

You're seeing a different behavior with `sh` because it behaves differently. Maybe your `sh` is bash, which doesn't perform any tail call optimization. Or maybe it's ksh93, which does perform tail call optimization but increments `SHLVL` even in that case.

Should zsh increment `SHLVL` in a tail call? There's no official standard for that, but it would make sense since tail calls are supposed to be an optimization and other than the process arrangements I'd expect the behavior to be the same. The fact that ATT ksh behaves differently is an indication that zsh shouldn't be doing this. Then again,

```
$ SHLVL=1 ksh -c 'echo $SHLVL; exec ksh -c "echo \$SHLVL"'
2
3
```

ksh93 increments `SHLVL` even with an explicit `exec`, and I don't think that makes sense: if the shell is being replaced, why is `SHLVL` changing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is a sticky mess. I was looking into `SHLVL` to guess whether the environment had been set up or not for interactive, but non-login shells, which can exist in the case of macOS for example b.c. it does not spawn a login shell at user login (the shell is a second-class citizen in macOS to it's proprietary mechanisms for setting up environment). It's too bad there is no standard; I really cannot rely on `SHLVL`.

Comment: `$SHLVL` comes from `tcsh`, not `ksh`. `zsh` behaves like `bash` and `tcsh` (and as I'd expect). I'd say `ksh93` is bogus here. See also the [discussion there](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2016/msg01609.html).

Comment: Note that it's not that `ksh` increments `$SHLVL`, it's that it doesn't decrement it when calling `exec` in the main process (like `tcsh`, `bash` or `zsh` do).

Comment: Note `bash` only does a `tail` call optimisation when running a _single_ command in `bash -c` (and in that case, it's bogus as already mentioned at that discussion above as it doesn't decrement `$SHLVL` like when calling `exec` explicitly. I'll raise the bug there).

Comment: both `tcsh` and `bash` have a bug in that they also decrement `$SHLVL` in `env SHLVL=1 tcsh -c '(exec printenv SHLVL); here'`